# How to compare two outputs in bash and find the CPU time?

Tags: bash

I want to calculate several CRC and compare them to see if any of them are alike. In other words x != y s.t. CRC(x) == CRC(y). The code I have written so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear;

echo "The script starts now" 
$SECONDS = 0;

while(true) 
  do    
    ./pycrc.py --model crc-32 --check-string $RANDOM
    ./pycrc.py --model crc-32 --check-string $RANDOM     
done

echo "The script is finish" 
echo "That took approximately $SECONDS seconds"
```

How do you manage to save the output from `./pycrc.py` and compare the variables?

Comment: This code isn't actually going to work; `$SECONDS = 0` evaluates `SECONDS`, it doesn't set it, because of the `$`, and the spaces mean it's not an assignment at all; you're running the command (for example) `611659` with the args `=` and `0`. What you want is `SECONDS=0`. Also, you're never going to get to the end because of that while(true) loop.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised `while(true)` works. Shell languages are in general very whitespace-sensitive. Please use `while true` instead - see [Compound Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands)

Comment: Unlike `[`, `(` is a metacharacter and can separate words. It just runs `true` in a subshell instead of the current shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) to capture the output and [Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) for the comparison.  Like so:

```
value1="$(./pycrc.py --model crc-32 --check-string $RANDOM)"
value2="$(./pycrc.py --model crc-32 --check-string $RANDOM)"

if [[ $value1 == $value2 ]]; then
  echo "Values match!"
fi
```